# TypeScript: Calling constructor in a loop doesn't create new objects but clones the previous one

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor

I am struggling with creating new objects inside of the loop in TypeScript.

**I have a model class:**

```
export class Person{
        
      firstName: string;
      lastName: string;
      age: number;
        
      constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string, age: number) {
        this.firstName= firstName;
        this.lastName= lastName;
        this.age= age;
      }
        
}
```

**service.ts**

```
let people = [];
let peopleObjects = [];

peopleHttpResponse.forEach(personResponse => {

    let person = new Person(
        personResponse.firstName,
        personResponse.lastName,
        personResponse.age);

     people.push(personResponse);
     peopleObjects.push(person);

});
```

In the results I have two arrays:

- `people` which contains all of the people I've received from http
  service (for example 100 unique persons)
- `peopleObjects` which contains 100 copies of identical person object

contains.

The problem is that, all of the persons within `peopleObjects` are identical. It looks like it contains a reference to the same object. Is it normal behavior for TypeScript? Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: straight off the bat, it doesn't look like there should be any weird reference issue. But can you try cast the personResponse as their model is the same ie : `peopleObjects.push(<Person>personResponse);`
And can you confirm the response is really not just the same details coming back ?

Comment: @Pogrindis I've tried to use `peopleObjects.push(personResponse as Person);` but it didn't help

Comment: This should work fine. Have a look at your compiled js and see if there is anything in that code.

Comment: Can we get a bit more info then on what `peopleHttpResponse` is ? Are they asyc responses for example ?

Comment: `peopleObjects.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(person)));` should solve it, or you should be able to solve it by wrapping the content inside the `forEach` in brackets. The only reason that could potentially explain what's happening is a `$scope` reference IF `peopleHttpResponse` is an Observable.

Comment: @Pogrindis `peopleHttpResponse` is a JSON response from the backend. Actually it's a fragment of the JSON, but it's not async.

Comment: @TusharShahi I think that was it. Clearing the cache, restarting IDE and rebuilding the projects resolved a problem. Really really weird. You can write an answer, I will accept it